# how to cast from intrusive_ptr<parent> to intrusive_ptr<child>?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have to get a child class pointer that is wrapped in boost's  [`intrusive_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#intrusive_ptr) from  `intrusive_ptr<parent_class>` returned by a class function.

```
class parent{...}
class child: public parent{...}


intrusive_ptr<parent>  GetElementPtr(ElementID Id)  {...};



/* in some other cpp file*/

ElementID XXX = ...;
intrusive_ptr<child> childElem = GetElementPtr(XXX); // cannot do so like this
```

Answer (score 1):

Either [`boost::static_pointer_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#static_pointer_cast) or [`boost::dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#dynamic_pointer_cast), depending on whether you are sure there is a `child` being pointed to. That is, the same determination you'd use to pick between `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` if you had a `parent *` and wanted a `child *`.